# The trackpad on my HP ProBook 4540s notebook suddenly stopped working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-12.04, touchpad

The trackpad on my HP ProBook 4540s notebook worked perfectly on both Windows and Ubuntu 12.04.

Then suddenly it stopped working on Ubuntu 12.04 but it work perfectly on Windows 7.

How can I enable the trackpad on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your drivers, remove the battery, turn the PC off and unplug all external devices.

If nothing of the previous worked for you, call HP, they will replace the TouchPad.

Answer (score 0):

See the value of `TouchpadOff` using:

```
synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff
```

If it's set to one, just enter this to enable it back:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=0
```